# Calculating mean values across groups in R

Tags: r

sorry for the beginner question in advance. I searched for an answer, but couldn't find a fitting one.

I have over 20 groups of 6 subjects each, all participating in the same study. All groups had the same test conditions and answered a number of items. I want a mean value per Item ***across all groups***, ***considered for possible effects within the groups***. Or does this average out anyway with the number of groups?

It's a data frame with the heading "group" "Item1" "Item2" "Item3" "..."

edit: This question was not answered in the thread above unfortunately

Comment: Can you give some code that demonstrates the shape of your data? Is it a dataframe? A list of some sort?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited my question, though I'm not sure how to insert a data frame correctly.

Comment: I can vote for re-open, but please note that you did not provide a reproducible example and the desired output. It is thus difficult to help you.

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248)

Answer (score 2):

To give you an example of self contained (reproducible) code, and an answer to what I think is your question:

```
myData <- data.frame(item1 = runif(n=10), item2 = rnorm(n=10), item3 = rt(n=10, df = 1))

means <- apply(myData, 2, mean)

print(means)
```

If this does not answer your question, then start by editing the above code to more accurately reflect the shape of your data, and give an example of the output.